# PHP замена тега другим тегом

Tags: php, html, функции

Подскажите, допустим у меня есть такая структура в html:

```
<div class="class1 ">
    <a>link</a>
</div>
<div class="class2">
    <a>link</a>
</div>
<div class="class1">
    <a>link</a>
</div>

<div class="class2">
    <a>link</a>
</div>
```

Мне нужна функция PHP которая найдет все div с классом class2 и внутри заменит `<a>` на `<span>`, но так, чтобы содержимое(то есть 'link') осталось неизменным.

Подскажите как это сделать пожалуйста

Comment: почему бы это не сделать на js?

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться библиотеками наподобие Simple HTML DOM:

```
$html = str_get_html($txt);
foreach($html->find(".class2 a") as $a){
    $a->outertext = "<span>" . $a->innertext . "</span>";
}

echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ещё один вариант - регулярные выражения *(но вариант с [Simple HTML DOM](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) предпочтительней)*:

```
$txt = preg_replace_callback(
    '~<div[^>]+class="class2"[^>]*>\K(.+?)(?=</div>)~s',
    function($m){
        return preg_replace('~<a[^>]*>(.+?)</a>~', '<span>$1</span>', $m[1]);
    },
    $txt
);

echo $txt;
```

---

**См.** [**Демо**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39b41264318374ceb3fcb6fdbed2bb2a4d8af455)